# Create a matrix for the combinations of two vectors

Tags: r, data-processing

I'm working in R and have two vectors (A and B) which have the same length. I want to form a matrix from A and B which counts unique combinations of terms.

For example, if A is `A <- c(1,1,1,2,3)` and B is `B <- <- c("a","a","b","b","b")`, I would want to produce a 3x2 matrix with rownames `1, 2, 3` and colnames `a, b`. Row 1 would be `2, 1`, 2 and 3 would be `0, 1`.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The `table()` function does this: `table(A,B)`

Answer (score 2):

I think `table(A,B)` is the simplest solution so far. Here is another option (thank @Onyambu's comment)

```
> xtabs(~.,cbind(A,B))
   B
A   a b
  1 2 1
  2 0 1
  3 0 1
```

Comment: mhh, I believe doing `xtabs(~., cbind(A, B))` should suffice. I often dont create the extra variable

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks a lot. I updated my answer with your advice.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(A, B) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = B, values_from = B,
     values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)%>%
  column_to_rownames('A') %>% 
  as.matrix
```

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding earlier I was using `count`, so the format may not be the correct oone

Comment: Okey, I see. I just noticed OP wants a 3-by-2 matrix...